# "Why did my pc restart" error Windows 10 VM Virtualbox

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

When I installed clean Windows 10 on my VM, it kept restarting until I had the problem, "Why did my pc restart", I was looking for clues that recovery needs to be restored to factory settings, so I did, and it doesn't work. Windows 10, and it still doesn't work, anyone knows?

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, after install you booted in and made a series of adjustments, after which the computer enters a boot loop? I would say to wipe the VM and start again fresh, but implement your changes one by one so that if you encounter this loop again, you'll have an idea of who the culprit is.

Comment: No. It was a fresh install. After "Just a Moment...." dialogue, windows reboots and shows the error mentioned earlier